# Install Google Chrome Nag

Tags: google-chrome

Good Morning All.
I am using Ubuntu 15.04 and Firefox 44.0. Software Centre keeps nagging to install Google Chrome, which I don't want.
Is there a way to turn off the nag?
Any assistance appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I have never seen something like this before. It also cannot be possible since Google Chrome is not in Software Centre  at all. Can you send a screenshot when you get it?

Comment: Could you please attach a screenshot to show how exactly its "nagging" ?

Comment: Do you mean "lag" ?? like hanging/freezing ?? and you want to avoid that ?? and also, are you referring "Chromium" ? because google chrome is not there in Default repos,..

Comment: Thanks for the help. Screenshot - /home/ted/Pictures/Screenshot from 2016-03-12 17:00:46.png

Comment: Screenshot left on your PC won't help anybody. Upload it to http://imgur.com and provide a link here.

Answer (score 0):

Since your Software Centre keeps nagging , install Google chrome via Terminal.

To install **GOOGLE CHROME** , first we need to add the Google Chrome PPA.

1.Import the Google Chrome PPA key from the command below.

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

2.Next set up the repository , by executing the below command.

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
```

3.Update the repositories.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

4.Install Google Chrome

```
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

**NOTE**:If you don't need need the stable version then install *google-chrome-beta* or *google-chrome-unstable* packages by giving

```
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-beta
```

**OR**

```
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-unstable
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I don't need to be stalked by Chrome, I am using Firefox and happy with it.